# Which versions of Ubuntu support absolute mouse mode?

Tags: kernel, mouse, usbhid

I am using a dual-head-KVM to connect to different dual-monitor systems.
The KVM uses absolute mouse mode to operate which works great if the operating system supports absolute mouse mode.

I am not that experienced with Linux, but I was told that the support for absolute mouse mode in Linux is or has not always been straight forward. The kernel needs to support it, then a udev-rule is needed to activate it(?) and depending on factors that I don't know it might be possible to operate the absolute mouse mode on both screens or just on the primary screen.

Can somebody shed some light on it?
I also read [here](https://sysmgt.lenovofiles.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Ftsm%2Fkvm_mouse_settings.html) that absolute mouse mode is supported in Ubuntu server starting from 16.04 and Ubuntu server starting from 14.04 which confused me even more because in the same table it states that with RHEL absolute mouse mode is supported starting with 7.3 and they use completely different kernels (to my understanding).
So, a lot of questionmarks :-)

Any help greatly appreciated!

J.